# She has been oversleeping on or in the train and missing her stops - which is the correct preposition?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> She has been oversleeping ***on*** the train and missing her stops.
>
> She has been oversleeping ***in*** the train and missing her stops.

Which is the correct *preposition* in the sentences above?

Comment: You are too quick to tick and accept the answer! Wait for others to give their opinion. But thanks for accepting. You can deselect this answer anytime (in case others come up with better and proper answer!). Cheers!

Comment: If I were to use this sentence, I would simply use *sleeping*, not *oversleeping*.  *Oversleeping* sounds weird to me as a native speaker, and *sleeping* already conveys everything you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a tricky question.

Generally, we travel *by* vehicles. Thus, *"I came by car"*, even though you are *in* the car. For most public transport such as trains and buses, we do things ***on*** them. That is - *'We read books on trains/planes'*

In your question, the medium of transportation is a train and thus, it'd take *on* as a preposition.

> She has been oversleeping *on* the train and missing her stops.

However, *in* is possible if you further describe the location in the train.

> She has been oversleeping *[in the train compartment](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-29700225)* and missing her stops.

Comment: This is incorrect, in general English uses "on" for these cases - probably short for "on board". You sleep in a car. You sleep on board a train/ship/boat/plane/etc.

Comment: +1 I used to fall asleep on the train all the time. I used to get bored on the subway every day. It is hard to fall asleep on a cruise ship. I fell asleep in the dining car.

Answer (score 4):

In British English we travel/go **by** most vehicles (train, bus, car, plane)  but we sit, stand, read books, etc, **on** the train, bus or plane (but **in** the car) [see Swan, *Practical English Usage* (2005.81)]. We would therefore normally (over)sleep **on** the train.

Comment: This is true also for AmE. Notice we can also *travel **by** foot* (indicating method of travel?) and *travel **on** foot (indicating what, that we are "on" our feet?). Interesting.

Comment: I think "by foot" is not commonly used. You're much more likely to hear "on foot".

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about aircraft, I fly **on** a large aircraft, **in** a small one.  The difference is whether I can stand up inside; equivalently, whether I walk aboard or seat myself from a standing position on the adjacent ground.  The same is applicable to boats.  Trains have room to stand up, so  one is always **on** them, even when asleep.  These are the usages that feel right to me.

Comment: Limited to vehicles, as I don't sleep on my home. I suspect it's short for "onboard".

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use "on" for a bus, train, plane to travel, it means in/into. It doesn't necessarily mean its roof. (Keep it in mind that you get on a bus, plane or train; similarly, when you are travelling, you are on it). (Please see Macmillan or Oxford in this connection). So the correct sentence is "She has been oversleeping on the train and missing her stops".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, as a native speaker (of American English), the preposition "on" in this context makes me think of travel, as in "on a journey". If I was sleeping in a train car that was sitting on some land, rather than train tracks, for example, I would use "in". I believe the reason is because it wouldn't be a vehicle in that case.