# which one is correct- Let's go on a bus/go in a bus/ go by a bus?

Tags: prepositions

which one is correct- Let's go on a bus/go in a bus/ go by a bus ? I am confused with these three options.

Comment: Related (and maybe a duplicate?): ["in" vs "on" with vehicles](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155). Also: [oversleeping in/on the train](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38186).

Answer (score 1):

When we're speaking of the mode of transport and not a specific vehicle we omit the article: "Let's go **by** bus", just like ***by*** {horse / train / car / airplane / boat / bicycle}, &c.

With most vehicles we use *on* when speaking either of location or the goal of movement:

> LOCATION: I left my laptop on the { horse / bus / tram / train / airplane / boat / bicycle}.
>   GOAL: I got on the {horse / bus / tram /train / airplane / boat / bicycle}.

With automobiles/cars, however, we use *in*:

> I got in the car.
>   I left my laptop in the car.

Railroad and tramcars usually take *in* for goals but either *in* or *on* for location.

Trucks swing both ways.