# Is there a difference between "I travel by train" and "I travel by a train"?

Tags: articles

I don't quite understand the usage of articles in such sentences.

As other example: "He goes to home by car". Grammar helper services suggest that I should not use an article there, but I don't understand why "He goes to home by a car" is invalid.

Comment: If we want to use the indefinite article, we use a different preposition: *He goes home **in** a car,* or *I am traveling **on** a train*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [which one is correct- Let's go on a bus/go in a bus/ go by a bus?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56433/which-one-is-correct-lets-go-on-a-bus-go-in-a-bus-go-by-a-bus) Itself closed as a duplicate, but not before being answered with *When we're speaking of the mode of transport and not a specific vehicle we omit the article: "**Let's go by bus**", just like by {horse / **train** / car / airplane / boat / bicycle}, &c.*

Comment: Well, the answer there covers it, but it's a different question and main objective is different (more about the usage of in/on/by). Not sure whether it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: He goes home, not to home.

Comment: "by a train" sounds like "near a train", while "by train" is "via train"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"By **a** train/car/whatever" is not idiomatic.  When we say "**by** *(means of transportation)*" we don't use an article.  That is just the idiomatic way to say it.

When we say "by car" or "by train", we are referring to *car* or *train* as a general phenomenon.  If we say "*a* car", it sounds like we're talking about "one of many possible cars", but that's not what we mean; we just mean that we use *car* as a means.

But we do use an article or other determiner if we phrase the sentence differently:

> I take **a/the train** to work
> I drive **my car** home every day

Only with *by* do we use no article.

(By the way, we also say "go home", not "go *to* home", because *home* in this context works like an adverb describing direction.)

Answer (score 0):

Correct: I travel **by train**. (Correct: I travel on the train.)

Incorrect: I travel by a train.

Correct: He goes home **by car**. (correct: He goes home in a car/in the car/in their car/ in our car/in my car.)

Incorrect: He goes home by a car.

**By** is used to say how we travel. We use by + noun without a/the/my etc.

They went by train. (NOT by the train)

I went by car. (NOT by my car)

by car/by bicycle/by bus/by train/by plane/by boat/by ferry/by ship

We use **in** for cars and taxis.

He came in a car. He came in the car. He came in a taxi. I came in their car. She went in my car.

but 'on my bike', 'on the boat'

We use **on** for bicycles and public transport.

They went on the train.

on the 4;30 train, on the plane, on the ferry, on the ship,

**On foot** means walking. I came on foot.