# Usuage of In & On?

Tags: prepositions, usage

They are more conflicts arising while using In & On in a sentence.
So I want to know some clarification regarding the usage of In & On in a sentence with a crystal clear example, because I'm in lot a confusion.

For Example:

> I'm on train; In time; In tour.
>
> I'm in train; On time; On tour.

My Question is :
What is the meaning of in & on? where to use? how can we able to distinguish (Is there any rule, If available)?

Please do clarify me?

Note: I have gone through [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125222/are-there-simple-rules-for-use-of-in-on-at-from-and-for). But have not get cleared still.

Comment: You have run into a driveby downvoter.  I'm not the downvoter, and my only guess is that the question was considered not high-level enough for this site. I can help a little.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [She has been oversleeping on or in the train and missing her stops - which is the correct preposition?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/she-has-been-oversleeping-on-or-in-the-train-and-missing-her-stops-which-is-th)

Comment: @Colleenv: Mainly My question is: I'm seeking for the answers of usage of In/On. Note: The Train & Tour sentences are just an example.

Answer (score 6):

The words *in* and *on* are old words, coming to us over the course of over one thousand years from Old English.  At times, in the development of the language, they were used interchangeably, which makes the history of their idiomatic use quite complicated.  *In* has the basic meaning of within or inside, and *on* has the basic meaning of in contact, but the idiomatic usage of each is impossible to determine from this.  Alas, you just have to memorize which word is used in which situation.

To make things even more interesting, the words have a broad range of meanings beyond the basic ones I mentioned. The *OED* finds over 40 separate meanings for *in* and about the same number for *on*.  Why are you ***on*** a train but ***in*** training?  Why can you be ***on*** tour but ***in*** a hurry?  Why can you be both ***on*** time and ***in*** time?

Alas, no easily stated rule exists to tell us.

Comment: This answer is not just in the ballpark, it's right on the mark (although it's not clear in my head why the original question wasn't asked on [ell.se]).